# Appending data to an already existing AudioBuffer object

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

I'm looking to append data to an *already* existing [AudioBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext.createBuffer) that is being played using web audio.

---

Upon receiving audio data to play, I create an [AudioBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext.createBufferSource) and then assign the data to the ArrayBuffer response.

```
    var audioBuffer = context.createBuffer(1, audioToPlay.length, 16000);
    audioBuffer.getChannelData(0).set(audioToPlay);
```

I then create a [buffer source node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext.createBufferSource) and hook up the audio buffer to the web audio context.

```
    var source = context.createBufferSource();
    source.buffer = audioBuffer;
    source.connect(context.destination);
    source.start(0);
```

Now, what I would like to do is append more data (another ArrayBuffer) to the *currently playing* buffer, while **avoiding** having to use the `onended` callback to create a new buffer..

Is there any way to do this? From what I can tell, this does not appear to be supported.

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14143652/web-audio-api-append-concatenate-different-audiobuffers-and-play-them-as-one-son

Comment: Yes - however, in this case, Im dealing with a stream (I don't have all the buffers up front)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot do this.  Once a playing buffer has been handed off to the audio thread via start(), you can't modify it.

However, that said, you absolutely should not be using onended, either.  What you should do is keep track of the last audiobuffer scheduled and the currentTime at which it was started, and create and play a NEW audio buffer at time = lastCurrentTimeStart+lastBufferDuration.  You should be able to get a smooth, uninterrupted playback.

Comment: Thanks for the validation. So it sounds like I will also have to track the state of the player? (i.e. if the user paused, if the playback rate was diff etc)

Comment: I asked this question here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77175414/how-schedule-audiobuffer-when-dealing-with-10-second-chunks  -- I seem to be doing it wrong