# How schedule audiobuffer when dealing with 10 second chunks?

Tags: web-audio-api

This is a follow up to this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26068642/73804

I am trying to smoothly play multiple short audio clips (and get the underlying bytes).  My implementation fails because the sound plays over itself and all the data is sent to analyzer at the same time.

```
playChunk(analyzer, "./test/output000.mp3", src, volume, 0);
playChunk(analyzer, "./test/output001.mp3", src, volume, 10); // 10 for 10-second wait


playChunk: async function (
    analyzer: any,
    file: string,
    src: any,
    volume: number,
    startNum: number
  ) {
    let audioContext = new AudioContext();
    let audio = new Audio(file);

    audio.crossOrigin = "anonymous";

    let mediaElementAudioSourceNode =
      audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audio);

    await audioContext.audioWorklet.addModule("testprocessor.js");

    let recorder = new AudioWorkletNode(audioContext, "testprocessor", {
      processorOptions: {
        someUsefulVariable: new Map([
          [1, "one"],
          [2, "two"],
        ]),
      },
    });

    const convertFloatToAudioBuffer = (data: any) => {
      const sampleRate = 8000 | audioContext.sampleRate;
      const channels = 1;
      const sampleLength = 128 | data.length; // 1sec = sampleRate * 1
      const audioBuffer = audioContext.createBuffer(
        channels,
        sampleLength,
        sampleRate
      ); // Empty Audio

      audioBuffer.copyToChannel(new Float32Array(data), 0); // depending on your processing this could be already a float32array
      return audioBuffer;
    };
    const streamDestination = audioContext.createMediaStreamDestination();

    let i = 0;
    const play = (data: any) => {
      if (!!data) {
        const audioBufferSourceNode = audioContext.createBufferSource(); // ?? move out of this function ??
        audioBufferSourceNode.buffer = convertFloatToAudioBuffer(data);
        analyzer.acceptWaveform(audioBufferSourceNode.buffer);
        audioBufferSourceNode.connect(streamDestination);
        audioBufferSourceNode.start(startNum);
      } else {
      }
    };

    recorder.port.onmessage = (ev: any) => play(ev.data);
    mediaElementAudioSourceNode.connect(recorder); // connect the processor with the source
    mediaElementAudioSourceNode.connect(audioContext.destination); // so speakers still work
    audio.play();

    return true;
  },
```