# Why does my second audio file not play using the currentTime property?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, audio-streaming, web-audio-api

I would like my audio2 file to play when audio1.currentTime is 3 seconds, but I'm not able to make it work. I'm a newbie in javascript, what am I missing?. This is my current javascript code:

```
    function initAudioPlayer(){
            var audio1, audio2, ext, agent;

            ext = ".mp3";
            agent = navigator.userAgent.toLocaleLowerCase();

            if(agent.indexOf('firefox') != -1 || agent.indexOf('opera') != -1) { ext = ".ogg";}


//Audio Objects: audio1 and audio2

            audio1 = new Audio();
            audio1.src = "folder/Audio1"+ext;
            audio1.loop = false;
            audio1.play();

            audio2 = new Audio();
            audio2.src = "folder/Audio2"+ext;
            audio2.loop = false;
            audio2.play();

//Function that reproduces the second audio file at second 3 of the first audio file

    function audio2(){
            if(audio1.currentTime == 3) {audio2.play();}
        };    
    }

    window.addEventListener("load", initAudioPlayer);
```

Comment: do you want to  merge theme and play final audio?

Comment: Yes @MehranHafizi! But one starts after the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Must use Audio Api and fetch buffers of your files.
Then you must plus each byte and copy to another new buffer.
this code can help you:

```
let idnex=0;
    samples.forEach(buufer => {


      if (index === 0) {
        tempBuf = buufer;
      } else {
        tempBuf = this.appendBuffer(tempBuf, buufer);
      }
      index++;
    });
```

and by thi method you can append two buffer:

```
 private appendBuffer(buffer1, buffer2) {


const numberOfChannels = Math.min(buffer1.numberOfChannels, buffer2.numberOfChannels);
const tmp = this.audioContextService.createBuffer(Math.max(buffer1.numberOfChannels, buffer2.numberOfChannels),
  Math.max(buffer1.length, buffer2.length), buffer1.sampleRate);

for (let i = 0; i < numberOfChannels; i++) {

  const channel = tmp.getChannelData(i);
  let finallArray = [];
  let d = [];
  const chanelTemp = buffer1.getChannelData(i);


  if (buffer2.numberOfChannels <= i) {

    finallArray = chanelTemp;
  } else {
    const c = buffer2.getChannelData(i);
    if (chanelTemp.length > c.length) {

      finallArray = chanelTemp;
      d = c;
    } else {

      finallArray = c;
      d = chanelTemp;
    }

    for (let j = 0; j < d.length; j++) {

      finallArray[j] += d[j] / 2;


    }

  }


  channel.set(finallArray, i);

}
```

you can see my demo [here](http://18.216.217.163)

---

Also You Can See [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14143652/web-audio-api-append-concatenate-different-audiobuffers-and-play-them-as-one-son)

Comment: I worked on it a lot  last year.if it can help you please check the answer as true

Answer (score 0):

If you truly want this to be accurate in time, you can't use Audio() - that's the HTML5 <audio> element, which is not sample-accurate.  Javascript is also not accurate enough in event delivery to use a callback to do this (to be fair, neither are most general-purpose native OS APIs).  You need to schedule the playback in advance, which is where Web Audio (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API) comes in.  You need to load both samples, decode them into AudioBuffers, and then schedule playing back each of them with an AudioBufferSourceNode.