# Can I use Javascript to mix multiple audio files into one audio?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

The Question:

Can I use Javascript to mix multiple audio files into one audio?

For example, I have a long people voice and a short background voice, and I need to get mixed audio which the background voice will play until people voice finish.

Is there any way that I achieve this with Javascript?

What I do:

I trying some audio third library like Tone.js and Howler.js, but still can't have any progress

If someone knows this, I will be very grateful, thinks.

Comment: You are going to combine two local mp3 files or resources from URL?

Comment: yeap , I want to combine two mp3 audio file , but I was trapped

Answer (score 1):

[ffmpeg.js](https://github.com/Kagami/ffmpeg.js) meets your needs. This library provides FFmpeg builds ported to JavaScript

---

For browers:

**Play two audios**

Listen to the end event of previous audio, and play next audio.

Ensure audios are loaded in advance and check if there is a blank frame where the two audios are connected.

Another way, play the second audio a few millseconds early.

**Concat two audios**

Use `AudioContext` API to concat two audio buffers. Refer to [Web Audio API append/concatenate different AudioBuffers and play them as one song](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14143652/web-audio-api-append-concatenate-different-audiobuffers-and-play-them-as-one-son)

Comment: thanks for answering my question, but in this situation, I want to deal with audio in the browser without any server, is ffmpeg.js can do this?